# Infinite universe - how does it expand?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

I have never taken a physics course but I am fascinated.

If the universe is infinite, how can it be expanding or shrinking?

How can it be that black holes are so strong, nothing even light can escape
them, but black holes are now seen as the brightest objects in the universe?

A layman's answer would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good video on the expansion of the universe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4c-gX9MT1Q and the reason that black holes "shine" (or rather, the disk around them shines) is describe here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJB7gbjiJKw . physics stackexchange is meant for technical work on physics, however, and so this question isn't really appropriate! This question would be more appropriate on a website like Quora.com or physicsforums.com.

Comment: Hi Ken Riddell, Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen this post, consider to only ask one question, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451) meta post.

Comment: Imagine a number line extending to infinity in both the positive and negative directions and with the distance between adjacent integers $1\mathrm{cm}$.  Now imagine that the distance between adjacent integers increases with time at the rate of $1\mathrm{cm/s}$.  The number line is infinite in extent but the spacing between adjacent integers is growing with time and *further*, as observed from *any* integer, the expansion seems centered there while the (instantaneous) speed with which the another integer recedes is proportional to the (instantaneous) distance between.